# Telegram Bot- размер inline_keyboard

Tags: telegram-bot

Подскажите как можно изменить размер inline_keyboard например 100% ширины экрана?
Если слово длинное telegram добавляет троеточие и не очень презентабельно получается.

Comment: никак, единственный вариант - это сделать одну кнопку в ряду, тогда у неё будет максимально возможная ширина

Comment: @Anatol, не факт. Даже если кнопка будет одна, то она подстраивается под содержимое. Чем более длинный текст, тем длиннее клавиатура. Но у неё есть предел отображения, на телефонах он меньше, а на компьютерах больше (в виду особенности размера экрана каждого из устройств).

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую. Размер кнопки меняется в зависимости от значения параметра row_width Вашей Inline-клавиатуры. Минимальное значение 1 (соответствует растяжению кнопки по длине текстового сообщения над оной), среднее значение 2 (делит место под текстовым сообщением пополам между двумя Inline-кнопками) и минимальное значение 3 (делит место под текстовым сообщением поровну между тремя Inline-кнопками).
Примеры:

```
from telebot import types
kb1 = Types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1) # самая длинная кнопка
kb2 = Types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) # деление пополам
kb3 = Types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3) # деление на три равных кнопки
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете инлайн клавиатуру(независимо от библиотеки) - ширина кнопок будет подстраиваться ****под текст отправленного сообщения** с учетом row_width**

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вроде на ответ похоже?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вопрос вроде как про ширину **клавиатуры**, а в «ответе» вижу лишь доп. информацию про поведение ширины **кнопок**. по-моему, это очень похоже на уточняющий комментарий к ответу N.L0rem

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, но ведь многоточие как раз добавляется на кнопку? Я никогда не видел, чтоб многоточие стояло вместо кнопок...

Comment: Откуда вы все вытягиваете магическое значение **row_width**!? Я может слепой но в оф. документации даже нет такого параметра.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если это текст будет без пробелов, в теории может быть. На практике не проверял.

Answer (score 0):

Есть один способ, не совсем корректный, но рабочий.

Краткое описание: Суть метода в создании N-го количества символов в одной из кнопок. Минус метода в том что вычислить автоматически ширину невозможно. Пользователю необходимо будет это сделать **вручную**. Потом на основании одного размера сделать функцию адаптивной клавиатуры. То есть, она будет высчитывать разницу в символах (основной текст) и корректировать количество пробелов для достижения наилучшего результата.

1. Создаем файл `config_user.json`

```
$config_user = json_decode(
    file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/botID/source/config_user.json'),
    true);
```

```
if ((!$config_user[$chat_id]) or ($input_key == 'message' and $config_user[$chat_id]['editing'] === true)) {
    $config_user[$chat_id] = [
        'keyboard_width' => 0,
        'keyboard_caption' => NULL,
        'remember' => false,
        'editing' => true
    ];
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/botID/source/config_user.json',
        json_encode($config_user, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
}
```

2. Отправляем сообщение:

```
if ($config_user[$chat_id]['editing'] === true) {
    $config_user[$chat_id] = [
        'keyboard_width' => 0,
        'keyboard_caption' => NULL,
        'remember' => false,
        'editing' => true
    ];
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/botID/source/config_user.json',
        json_encode($config_user, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    TelegramAPI::sendMessage($text_control['message']['start']['edit_width'], TelegramKeyboard::widthEdit());
} else
    TelegramAPI::sendMessage($text_control['message']['start']['default'], TelegramKeyboard::mainMenu());
```

Класс TelegramAPI:

```
class TelegramAPI
{
    /**
     * @var int $chat_id ID пользователя/чата
     * @var string $parse_mode Режим разбора сущностей в тексте сообщения
     * @var bool $protect_content Защищает содержимое отправленного сообщения от пересылки и сохранения
     */
    public static int $chat_id;
    public static string $parse_mode = 'html';
    public static bool $protect_content = false;
    public static int|null $message_id;
    private static string $url;

    /**
     * @param string $token
     * @return void
     */
    public static function init(string $token): void
    {
        self::$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/";
    }

    /**
     * ---
     * @param string $method Метод API
     * @param array $request_params Готовый запрос для отправки
     * @return bool|array|string
     */
    private static function curl(string $method, array $request_params): bool|array|string
    {
        $ch = curl_init(self::$url . $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_params);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * ---
     * @param string $text Текст отправляемого сообщения
     * @param string|null $reply_markup Дополнительные возможности интерфейса
     * @return bool|array|string
     */
    public static function sendMessage(string $text = 'Hello, World!', ?string $reply_markup = null): bool|array|string
    {
        return static::curl(__FUNCTION__, [
            'chat_id' => self::$chat_id,
            'text' => $text,
            'parse_mode' => self::$parse_mode,
            'protect_content' => self::$protect_content,
            'reply_markup' => $reply_markup
        ]);
    }
}
```

Класс TelegramKeyboard:

```
class TelegramKeyboard
{
    private static string $keyboardType;
    private static array $keyboard = [];
    private static int $row = 0;

    public static array $text_control;
    public static ?string $width_caption = null;
    public static ?int $width_value = null;

    /**
     * @param string $keyboardType
     * @param bool $resize_keyboard
     * @param bool $oneTimeKeyboard
     * @return void
     */
    private static function init(
        string $keyboardType = 'inline_keyboard',
        bool   $resize_keyboard = true,
        bool   $oneTimeKeyboard = false): void
    {
        self::$text_control = self::$text_control['keyboard'];
        self::$keyboardType = $keyboardType;
        static::$keyboard = [
            $keyboardType => [],
            'resize_keyboard' => $resize_keyboard,
            'one_time_keyboard' => $oneTimeKeyboard
        ];
        static::$row = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    private static function nextRow(): void
    {
        static::$row++;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $inline_mode
     * @param string|null $inline_value
     * @param string|null $text
     * @param string|null $callback_action
     * @param string|null $callback_type
     * @param string|null $callback_variation
     * @return void
     */
    private static function addRow(
        string  $inline_mode = 'callback_data',
        string  $inline_value = null,
        string  $text = null,
        ?string $callback_action = null,
        ?string $callback_type = null,
        ?string $callback_variation = null): void
    {
        switch ($inline_mode) {
            case 'callback_data':
                $button = [
                    "text" => $text,
                    "callback_data" => $callback_action ? "action:$callback_action" : 'null'
                ];

                if ($callback_type) {
                    $button["callback_data"] .= "|type:$callback_type";
                }

                if (!is_null($callback_variation)) {
                    $button["callback_data"] .= "|variation:$callback_variation";
                }
                break;

            default:
                $button = [
                    "text" => $text,
                    $inline_mode => $inline_value
                ];
                break;
        }

        static::$keyboard[self::$keyboardType][static::$row][] = $button;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $text Текст для отображения
     * @return string
     */
    private static function adaptedKeyboard(string $text): string
    {
        if (($count = iconv_strlen($text)) > 14) {
            self::$width_caption = substr(self::$width_caption, 0, -($count - 13));
        }

        return "ㅤ" . self::$width_caption . $text . self::$width_caption . "ㅤ";
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public static function widthEdit(): bool|string
    {
        self::init();

        self::addRow(
            text: self::adaptedKeyboard('Save Button'),
            callback_action: "keyboard_width",
            callback_type: "save_width",
            callback_variation: self::$width_value);

        self::nextRow();

        self::addRow(
            text: self::$text_control['width']['decrease'],
            callback_action: 'keyboard_width',
            callback_variation: 'decrease');

        self::addRow(
            text: self::$text_control['width']['increase'],
            callback_action: 'keyboard_width',
            callback_variation: 'increase');

        return json_encode(self::$keyboard);
    }

    public static function mainMenu(): bool|string
    {
        self::init();
        self::addRow(
            text: self::adaptedKeyboard(self::$text_control['main_menu']['search']),
            callback_action: 'searchMainMenu');
        self::nextRow();
        self::addRow(text: 'Button 1');
        self::addRow(text: 'Button 2');

        return json_encode(self::$keyboard);
    }
}
```

3. Обработка нажатой кнопки:

```
/* Если отправлено продолжить */
if ($callback['type'] == 'save_width') {
    $callback['variation']-- > is_integer($callback['variation']);
    $config_user[$chat_id] = [
        'keyboard_width' => $callback['variation'] + 1,
        'keyboard_caption' => str_repeat(" ", $callback['variation'] + 1),
        'remember' => false,
        'editing' => false
    ];
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/botID/source/config_user.json',
        json_encode($config_user, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    TelegramAPI::editMessageText(
        $text_control['start']['complete'],
        TelegramKeyboard::mainMenu());
} else {
    /* Проверка типа нажатой кнопки */
    $callback['variation'] = match ($callback['variation']) {
        'decrease' => $config_user[$chat_id]['keyboard_width'] - 1, #Добавляем 1 символ к ширине
        'increase' => $config_user[$chat_id]['keyboard_width'] + 1, #Убираем 1 символ к ширине
    };
    if ($callback['variation'] > 42) #Если $callback вышел больше 42, то устанавливаем значение 42
        $callback['variation'] = 42;
    elseif ($callback['variation'] < 0) #Если $callback вышел меньше 0, то устанавливаем значение 0
        $callback['variation'] = 0;
    /* Передаём значения в массив */
    #Генерируем N-количество пустых символов
    $config_user[$chat_id]['keyboard_caption'] = str_repeat(" ", $callback['variation']);
    $config_user[$chat_id]['keyboard_width'] = $callback['variation'];
    /* Сохраняем полученные данные в config_user.json */
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/botID/source/config_user.json',
        json_encode($config_user, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
    /* Передача значений */
    TelegramKeyboard::$width_caption = $config_user[$chat_id]['keyboard_caption'];
    TelegramKeyboard::$width_value = $config_user[$chat_id]['keyboard_width'];
    /* Редактировать ранее отправленное сообщение */
    TelegramAPI::editMessageText(
        $text_control['start']['edit_width'],
        TelegramKeyboard::widthEdit());
}
```

Результат:

Минимальный размер: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

+/- средний размер: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Максимальный размер: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. Не обращайте внимание на то что в коде кнопок меньше чем на скриншотах. Работоспособность от этого не меняется.

Answer (score -1):

Никак. Максимальная длина будет только если row_width=1

Comment: что такое *row_width*?

Comment: @Anatol, бред сумасшедшего, такого параметра нет в оф. документации Telegram Bot API.